# How do I delete the connection between these 2 vectors?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am new to blender and I am trying to make a neon sign

I have this connection here that I am trying to delete

[image]

when I delete the vectors on the curve I get this

[image]

I am trying to have this as empty space but nothing I am doing is working to delete this connection

**Edit:**

I figured it out, I selected the 3 points and split it
then I deleted the split points

which got me what I wanted

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select the controls that define the segments you want to delete, then x-> delete segments:

[image]

This works for curves with their own geometry.  Note that some uses of curves, like a curve modifier, are only built around the existence of a single spline inside any given curve object; you may not get the results you expect.

Comment: When I tried deleting the segment it would keep the connection. I figured it out by splitting the segment then deleting that sectiong. Thanks for your help!